# How to make Feature Module state cached globally from many lazy loading modules?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have two feature modules (1) user profile and (2) blogs. The application lazy load these modules based on routes **userprofile** and **blogs** (1) http://localhost/userprofile and (2) http://localhost/blogs. When the routes change, there is an effect that calls an http service to retrieve the data from the server.

I want to prevent the **http** calls from the second time onwards and get the data from the application cache when the route changes. How do I design the app wide caching of the user profile and blogs so retrieving the data is from the global cache and don't make http calls?

I don't want to create a single store in the application at the application level for **user profile** and **blogs** because the feature modules will be used as a library (code reuse) by other applications so need to have code for those specific feature modules.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if there is already something in the store or not before making the call

```
@Effect()
getOrder = this.actions.pipe(
  ofType<GetOrder>(ActionTypes.GetOrder),
  withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(getOrders))),
  filter(([{payload}, orders]) => !!orders[payload.orderId])
  mergeMap([{payload}] => {
    ...
  })
)
```

See my post [Start using ngrx/effects for this](https://blog.angularindepth.com/start-using-ngrx-effects-for-this-e0b2bd9da165) for more info.

Comment: The problem that I have is the stores are in two lazy loading modules. So when the route changes, the store in the existing module will be cleared. When the route changes again back to the same, the store will be built from scratch again. My question is around how to have a global store with stores from different features and they are available all the time when the route changes.